# Как разбить номер карты по 4 знака и выводить первые 6 и последние 4 цифры номера, а вместо остальных звездочки?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как разбить номер карты по 4 знака и выводить первые 6 и последние 4 цифры номера,  а вместо остальных звездочки? Например: Visa Platinum 7000 79** **** 6361

```
[{'date': '07.12.2019 06:17:14', 'description': 'Перевод организации', 'from': 'Visa Classic 2842878893689012', 'to': 'Счет 35158586384610753655', 'operationAmount': {'amount': '48150.39', 'currency': {'name': 'USD', 'code': 'USD'}}}, {'date': '19.11.2019 09:22:25', 'description': 'Перевод организации', 'from': 'Maestro 7810846596785568', 'to': 'Счет 43241152692663622869', 'operationAmount': {'amount': '30153.72', 'currency': {'name': 'руб.', 'code': 'RUB'}}}]
```

номер карты под ключом from

Comment: что не получилось? звездочки вывести?

Comment: У меня в целом нет кода для реализации, только пример вывода

Comment: Без ваших попыток решения вопрос будет закрыт. Задача простая, можно самому  и попробовать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
card = "Visa Classic 2842878893689012"
card_number = card.split()[-1]

private_number = card_number[:6] + (len(card_number[6:-4]) * '*') + card_number[-4:]

chunks, chunk_size = len(private_number), len(private_number)//4
print(" ".join([ private_number[i:i+chunk_size] for i in range(0, chunks, chunk_size) ]))
```

Вывод: 2842 87** **** 9012

Answer (score 0):

```
d={'date': '07.12.2019 06:17:14', 'description': 'Перевод организации', 'from': 'Visa Classic 2842878893689012',
   'to': 'Счет 35158586384610753655', 'operationAmount': {'amount': '48150.39', 'currency': {'name': 'USD', 'code': 'USD'}}}

print(d['from'].split()[2][:6]+'***'+d['from'].split()[2][-4:])
```

Вывод:

```
284287***9012
```

Comment: так тут символов не хватает

Comment: Это элемент секьюрности, защита от ботов, а количество символов в номере карты всегда одинаково, звезд можно наставить сколько угодно, можно и пробелы вставить, и другие символы.

Comment: Ну так, у номера карты 16 символов, почему у Вас в итоге меньше? Некорректное отображение.

Comment: Смотри сообщение выше.